# Randomize specific results from a table with UNION

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using UNION to put 3 queries together into one result. For one of the queries, I want to randomize their placement in the "master table" and the other 2 queries not be ranadomized. Sort of like randomizing ad placements in a group of products. I could do this with PHP easily, but I'm wondering if there is an easy MySQL way.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that from `Query1 UNION Q2 UNION Q3`, you want the order of the result set to be all from Q1 together, followed by all from Q2 together, and the rows from Q3 interspersed throughout the rows from Q1 and Q2? If you could add a simple example, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the hard way, but you could add a "random number" column to the table you want randomized and populate it with `RAND()` -- and then you can order that table by that column.

You might be able to even say `SELECT *, RAND() AS sortorder FROM mytable ORDER BY sortorder ASC` but honestly I'm not sure if that'll work, and I don't have a MySQL server on my current workstation to try it :)